# Get thumbnail from ALAssetsRepresentation as NSData

Tags: ios, thumbnails, nsdata, alassetslibrary

I am writing `NSData` to a file and saving it in the device's app documents folder. For that, is it possible to get thumbnail from `ALAssetsRepresentation` object in `NSData` format. If so, any helpful links to that?

I couldn't find anything similar, other than getting CGImageRef from `ALAssetsRepresentation`. I don't want `CGImageRef` format as I have to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to convert it to `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
GImageRef iref = [myasset thumbnail];

if (iref)
{
   UIImage *theThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
   NSData *thumnailData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(theThumbnail);

}
```